# Let $A$ an $R$-ideal, $M$ a submodule generated by $n$ elements, $x \in R$ with $xM \subset AM$. Show that $(x^n+y)M = 0$ for some $y \in A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $A$ an ideal in $R$, $M$ an $R$-module generated by $n$ elements, and $x$ an element of $R$ satisfying $xM \subset AM$. Show that $(x^n+y)M=0$ for some $y \in A$.

I am not sure how I would go about this problem, even for the case $n = 1$: Suppose $M = Rm$ for some $m \in  M$. Let $rm \in M$ be an arbitrary element. Then $xrm = ar_1m$ for some $r_1 \in R, a \in A$. Then $(xr-ar_1)m = 0$, with $-ar_1 \in A$. But the problem now is how I would be able to "get rid of" $r$ term of $xr$. How would I be able to do the general case?

Comment: I definitely don't see how to answer the question, but did you try thinking about Nakayama's Lemma?  A lot of the hypotheses and conclusions feel similar.

Comment: Sorry but no, and the chapter from which thusbquestuon was taken does not deal with it.

Comment: [sorry it doesn't format very well.] Does something like this work in the case n = 2?
Say m1, m2 generate M.
Write 
xm1 = a_{11} m1 + a_{12} m2 and 
xm2 = a_{21} m1 + a_{21} m2.
Then can we find y using the characteristic polynomial of the matrix (a_{ij})?  Is that closer to what was covered in the chapter?

Comment: Adapt the proof of Proposition 2.4 on page 21 of Atiyah and MacDonald, Commutative Algebra (which is in fact used to prove Nakayama's lemma).  Sorry I can't write more right now.  I'll provide more detail tomorrow if you haven't worked this out already.

Comment: Thanks fredgoodman. If you could explain the answer with little linear algebra as possible that woud be great; as much as I know the basic concepts of linear algebra, the chapter does not deal extensively with lin alg and so I assume that little would have to be used.

Comment: @CuteBrownie ... are you confusing linear algebra with commutative algebra? And it’s hard to understand why you’d be shying away from linear algebra, which gives all the intuition for modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the proof from page 21 in Atiyah and MacDonald, or from page 120 of Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra.  It requires some facts about determinants.  Determinants make sense for square matrices over a commutative ring, and the formulas which you may know for determinants of matrices over fields are equally valid in this context.  In particular, for any square matrix $Y$, there is an associated matrix $C(Y)$ called the cofactor matrix with the property that $$C(Y) Y = Y C(Y) = \det(Y) E,$$ where $E$ denotes the identity matrix.  Moreover, $\det(x E - Y) = x^n + y$, where $y$ is in the ideal generated by the entries of $Y$.

Square matrices of size $n$-by-$n$ over $R$ form a non-commutative ring and $M^n$ is a module over this ring, via matrix multiplication.

Suppose that your module $M$ is generated by $m_1, \dots, m_n$. Let $\mathbf m = \begin{bmatrix} m_1 \\ \vdots \\ m_n \end{bmatrix} \in M^n$.

For each $i$, there exist $a_{i, j} \in A$ such that
$$
x m_i = \sum_j a_{i, j} m_j.
$$
Define the matrix $Y = (a_{i, j})$.   Then the previous displayed equation is equivalent to 
$$
(x E - Y)\, \mathbf m = 0.
$$
Multiplying on the left by the cofactor matrix of $x E - Y$, one gets
$\det(x E - Y) E \, \mathbf m = 0$, or $\det(x E - Y) m_i = 0$ for all $i$.  Since the elements $m_i$ generate $M$, this means $\det(x E - Y)M = 0$.  But as observed previously, $\det(x E - Y) = x^n + y$, where $y \in A$.

Comment: I like your answer!  I personally would be surprised if there is a proof that doesn't use these sorts of concepts from linear algebra (or Nakayama's lemma where they're hidden in the proof).